# grep -f maximum number of patterns?

Tags: unix, grep

I'd like to use grep on a text file with -f to match a long list (10,000) of patterns. Turns out that grep doesn't like this (who, knew?). After a day, it didn't produce anything. Smaller lists work almost instantaneously.

I was thinking I might split my long list up and do it a few times. Any idea what a good maximum length for the pattern list might be?

Also, I'm rather new with unix. Alternative approaches are welcome. The list of patterns, or search terms, are in a plaintext file, one per line.

Thank you everyone for your guidance.

Comment: Are you looking for lines containing "any of these 10k terms"?

Comment: I think it should have been fairly obvious that grepping for n patterns in a file of size m is **O(n*m)**. Unless you can coalesce your patterns into fewer patterns (by noticing common parts in certain patterns and judicious use of `|` in the regular expressions), I don't see how you could really improve on this without prebuilding some kind of index. If you don't do that and just use naive `grep`, then, as always, you need to determine the maximum sizes of n and m that are acceptable *to you in your use case* through testing and benchmarking.

Comment: How much smaller are the lists that work instanteneously? Could you show a few lines from the pattern file?

Comment: A list of 10 was what I just tried. Just Twitter usernames separated by line. Just tried a list of 1000, no output after 10 minutes.

Comment: I could arrange those patterns in a hierarchy (some tree structure) you could save a lot of comparisons

Comment: Unfortunately there is no hierarchy. It's all unstructured data.

Comment: If you can sort the target file by the twitter names (do they have a @ attached to them? That would make it easier...) and separately sort the file with the names you are looking for, the order of the problem you are solving will be much, much smaller. I think that it's not simply O(n*m) as Celada said - I suspect that there is a fair bit of memory shuffling going on in grep as each expression is being evaluated. If that's true, then splitting into smaller groups will be correspondingly faster - it might be that the problem is not linear in n (# of expressions) but quadratic. Just a hunch.

Comment: I just tried a similar thing - checking a list of 272 names against a file with 30k lines. That may be much smaller than your problem; it took just 0.367 seconds on an old mac. Using `time grep -f file1 file2` will tell you how long things take. Run this with 50, 100, 200 names and see what happens. It may be that at a certain point you run into memory (swap) issues after which time will explode. If the process takes a long time to run, open another window and use `top` to find out how much memory is used; or use the `free` command. Usually when things "hang", lack of memory is the culprit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i got the same problem with approx. 4 million patterns to search for in a file with 9 million lines. Seems like it is a problem of RAM. so i got this neat little work around which might be slower than splitting and joining but it just need this one line.

```
 while read line; do grep $line fileToSearchIn;done < patternFile
```

I needed to use the work around since the `-F` flag is no solution for that large files...

EDIT: This seems to be really slow for large files. After some more research i found 'faSomeRecords' and really other awesome tools from Kent [NGS-editing-Tools](http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Kent_source_utilities)

I tried it on my own by extracting 2 million fasta-rec from 5.5million records file. Took approx. 30 sec..

cheers

EDIT: [direct download link](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/linux.x86_64/)

Answer (score 8):

From comments, it appears that the patterns you are matching are fixed strings.  If that is the case, you should definitely use `-F`.  That will increase the speed of the matching considerably.  (Using 479,000 strings to match on an input file with 3 lines using `-F` takes under 1.5 seconds on a moderately powered machine.  Not using `-F`, that same machine is not yet finished after several minutes.)

Comment: What an amazingly simple solution. Works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: Eats a lot of memory/RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash script you can run on your files (or if you would like, a subset of your files). It will split the key file into increasingly large blocks, and for each block attempt the grep operation. The operations are timed - right now I'm timing each grep operation, as well as the total time to process all the sub-expressions.
Output is in seconds - with some effort you can get ms, but with the problem you are having it's unlikely you need that granularity.
Run the script in a terminal window with a command of the form

`./timeScript keyFile textFile 100 > outputFile`

This will run the script, using keyFile as the file where the search keys are stored, and textFile as the file where you are looking for keys, and 100 as the initial block size. On each loop the block size will be doubled.

In a second terminal, run the command

`tail -f outputFile`

which will keep track of the output of your other process into the file `outputFile`

I recommend that you open a third terminal window, and that you run `top` in that window. You will be able to see how much memory and CPU your process is taking - again, if you see vast amounts of memory consumed it will give you a hint that things are not going well.

This should allow you to find out when things start to slow down - which is the answer to your question. I don't think there's a "magic number" - it probably depends on your machine, and in particular on the file size and the amount of memory you have.

You could take the output of the script and put it through a grep:

`grep entire outputFile`

You will end up with just the summaries - block size, and time taken, e.g.

`Time for processing entire file with blocksize 800: 4 seconds`

If you plot these numbers against each other (or simply inspect the numbers), you will see when the algorithm is optimal, and when it slows down.

Here is the code: I did not do extensive error checking but it seemed to work for me. Obviously in your ultimate solution you need to do something with the outputs of grep (instead of piping it to `wc -l` which I did just to see how many lines were matched)...

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to look at difference in timing
# when grepping a file with a large number of expressions
# assume first argument = name of file with list of expressions
# second argument = name of file to check
# optional third argument = initial block size (default 100)
#
# split f1 into chunks of 1, 2, 4, 8... expressions at a time
# and print out how long it took to process all the lines in f2

if (($# < 2 )); then
  echo Warning: need at leasttwo parameters.
  echo Usage: timeScript keyFile searchFile [initial blocksize]
  exit 0
fi

f1_linecount=`cat $1 | wc -l`
echo linecount of file1 is $f1_linecount

f2_linecount=`cat $2 | wc -l`
echo linecount of file2 is $f2_linecount
echo

if (($# < 3 )); then
  blockLength=100
else
  blockLength=$3
fi

while (($blockLength < f1_linecount))
do
  echo Using blocks of $blockLength
  #split is a built in command that splits the file
  # -l tells it to break after $blockLength lines
  # and the block$blockLength parameter is a prefix for the file
  split -l $blockLength $1 block$blockLength
  Tstart="$(date +%s)"
  Tbefore=$Tstart

  for fn in block*
    do
      echo "grep -f $fn $2 | wc -l"
      echo number of lines matched: `grep -f $fn $2 | wc -l`
      Tnow="$(($(date +%s)))"
      echo Time taken: $(($Tnow - $Tbefore)) s
      Tbefore=$Tnow
    done
  echo Time for processing entire file with blocksize $blockLength: $(($Tnow - $Tstart)) seconds
  blockLength=$((2*$blockLength))
  # remove the split files - no longer needed
  rm block*
  echo block length is now $blockLength and f1 linecount is $f1_linecount
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for this. 

To the future reader: this really would optimize the time for each grep. For my particular case, this wasn't necessary, because the patterns were fixed strings, and -F sped up the process exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly give sed a try to see whether you get a better result, but it is a lot of work to do either way on a file of any size. You didn't provide any details on your problem, but if you have 10k patterns I would be trying to think about whether there is some way to generalize them into a smaller number of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl script "match_many.pl" which addresses a very common subset of the "large number of keys vs. large number of records" problem.   Keys are accepted one per line from stdin.  The two command line parameters are the name of the file to search and the field (white space delimited) which must match a key.  This subset of the original problem can be solved quickly since the location of the match (if any) in the record is known ahead of time and the key always corresponds to an entire field in the record.  In one typical case it searched 9400265 records with 42899 keys, matching 42401 of the keys and emitting 1831944 records in 41s.   The more general case, where the key may appear as a substring in any part of a record, is a more difficult problem that this script does not address.  (If keys never include white space and always correspond to an entire word the script could be modified to handle that case by iterating over all fields per record, instead of just testing the one, at the cost of running M times slower, where M is the average field number where the matches are found.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $kcount;
my ($infile,$test_field) = @ARGV;
if(!defined($infile) || "$infile" eq "" || !defined($test_field) || ($test_field <= 0)){
  die "syntax: match_many.pl infile field" 
}
my %keys;       # hash of keys
$test_field--;  # external range (1,N) to internal range (0,N-1)

$kcount=0;
while(<STDIN>) {
   my $line = $_;
   chomp($line);
   $keys {$line} = 1;
   $kcount++
}
print STDERR "keys read: $kcount\n";

my $records = 0;
my $emitted = 0;
open(INFILE, $infile )  or die "Could not open $infile";
while(<INFILE>) {
   if(substr($_,0,1) =~ /#/){ #skip comment lines
     next;
   }
   my $line = $_;
   chomp($line);
   $line =~ s/^\s+//;
   my @fields = split(/\s+/, $line);
   if(exists($keys{$fields[$test_field]})){
      print STDOUT "$line\n";
      $emitted++;
      $keys{$fields[$test_field]}++;
   }
   $records++;
}

$kcount=0;
while( my( $key, $value ) = each %keys ){
   if($value > 1){ 
      $kcount++; 
   }
}

close(INFILE);
print STDERR "records read: $records, emitted: $emitted; keys matched: $kcount\n";

exit;
```