# How to copy only that data to a file which is not present in that file in shell script / bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to put some data in a file which should be unique.
suppose in 
file1 I have following data.

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

and now I want to add `MNO DES ABC` then it should only copy "MNO" and "DES" as "ABC" is already present.
file1 should look like

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
MNO
DES
```

(ABC should be there for only once.)

Comment: how do you want to make the check "if it is not in the destination file", do you mean line by line comparisons?

Comment: Are they sorted files?  Is it OK to keep them sorted?

Comment: Can you give an example of the two input files and the expected output?

Comment: Is it ok if the file will get sorted?

Comment: @AkshayB - see updated answer - you can do it in one step too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easiest way:** this sholud add non-matching line in `f1`

```
diff -c f1 f2|grep ^+|awk -F '+ ' '{print $NF}' >> f1
```

*or if '+ ' is going to be a part of actual text:*

```
diff -c f1 f2|grep ^+|awk -F '+ ' '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' >> f1
```

---

**shell script way:**

I have compare script that compares line counts/lenght etc.. but for your requirement I think below part should do the job....

**input:**

```
$ cat f1
ABC
XYZ
PQR
$ cat f2
MNO
DES
ABC
```

**output after script***

```
$ ./compareCopy f1 f2
-----------------------------------------------------
 comparing f1 f2
-----------------------------------------------------
Lines check - DONE
$ cat f1
ABC
XYZ
PQR
DES
MNO
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# != "2" ]; then
  echo
  echo "Requires arguments from command prompt"
  echo "Usage: compare <file1> <file2>"
  echo
  exit
fi

proc="compareCopy"
#sort files for line by line compare
cat $1|sort > file1.tmp
cat $2|sort > file2.tmp

echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo " comparing $1 $2" |tee ${proc}_compare.result
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"

file1_lines=`wc -l $1|cut -d " " -f1`
file2_lines=`wc -l $2|cut -d " " -f1`

#Check each line
x=1
while [ "${x}" -le "${file1_lines}" ]
do
  f1_line=`sed -n ${x}p file1.tmp`
  f2_line=`sed -n ${x}p file2.tmp`

        if [ "${f1_line}" != "${f2_line}" ]; then
         echo "line number ${x} don't match in both $1 and $2 files" >> ${proc}_compare.result
         echo "$1 line: "${f1_line}"" >> ${proc}_compare.result
         echo "$2 line: "${f2_line}"" >> ${proc}_compare.result
         # so add this line in file 1
         echo $f2_line >> $1
        fi
x=$[${x} +1]
done

rm -f file1.tmp file2.tmp
echo "Lines check - DONE" |tee -a ${proc}_compare.result
```

Comment: Seems very inefficient for large files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgrep`:

```
fgrep -vf file1 file2 > file2.tmp && cat file2.tmp >> file1 && rm file2.tmp
```

which fetches all lines of `file2` that are not in `file1` and appends the result to `file1`.

You may want to take a look at this post: [grep -f maximum number of patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428191/grep-f-maximum-number-of-patterns)

Comment: ok thanks and suppose I want to copy some text say "abc" to a file without duplicating then what should I use??

Comment: @codeforester - it should be `fgrep -f file2 file1`

Answer (score 0):

`Perl one liner`

**file one:**
1
2
3

**file two:**
1
4
3

**Print Only Unique Line**
`perl -lne 'print if ++$n{ $_ } == 1 ' file_one.txt file_two.txt`

**Or**

`perl -lne 'print unless ++$n{ $_ } '  file_one.txt file_two.txt`

**output**
1
4
3
2

Answer (score 0):

The natural way:

```
sort -u File1 File2 >Temp && mv Temp File1
```

The tricky way if the files are already sorted:

```
comm File1 File2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' >Temp && mv Temp File1
```