# How the performance of grep scales, when using -f option (OR style string match by using a list of strings file)?

Tags: performance, optimization, grep, scalability, bigdata

I have a huge list of network edges (tens of millions) in .abc format (space delimited: label1 label2 weight) and a list of labels in a file-x. I want to use grep to query all lines, which have label2 matching with a label present in file-x (.csv with one label per line). So `grep -f` is perfect for me, since I have added a space prefix for the labes in file-x (so, that they don't match with the label1).

However, the scalability is not "stable". If I run two hundred lines of file-x (file-x.200) I get very slow performance:

```
time grep -f file-x.200 links.abc > res.abc                                                                     

real    17m12.641s
user    16m8.964s
sys     0m31.188s
```

When I split the two hunderd lines and run them separately (in sequence), I get similar performance as when I run the grep with only one label.

First run:

```
time grep -f file-x.200-1 links.abc > res.abc                                                                     

real    0m16.803s
user    0m15.168s
sys     0m0.876s
```

Second run:

```
time grep -f file-x.200-2 links.abc > res.abc                                                                     

real    0m17.413s
user    0m15.972s
sys     0m0.716s
```

The resulting test.csv files are identical.

When I run it with one line in the file-x:

```
time grep -f file-x.1 links.abc > res.abc                                                                     

real    0m5.250s
user    0m0.768s
sys     0m0.592s
```

It seems, that disk look-up takes approx 4.5s.

By running some more experiments, using I discovered these (label amount, boost per label performance compared to one label):

- 20 x2
- 100 x5
- 120 x5.7
- 150 x3.5

So something happens, between moving from list of 120 labels to 150.

I would like to understand what happens here and how I can approach towards a safe limit for the label set length?

I am using GNU version of grep. The memory foot print is very low.

EDIT: I ran some more tests. It seems, that set >120 does not always perform slow, which makes me suspect SSD write magic or virtual CPU magic. I will run more tests tomorrow using /dev/shm with a dedicated CPU.

EDIT 2: When using /dev/shm and dedicated CPU the fluctuation vanished, but grepping with 150 is much slower, than 120. Different set of 150 is always slow, but the size of output seems to be a factor (writing it to /dev/shm), however, the size of output doesn't matter as much as the amount of parameters. If I grep with thousand copies of same line, the time is near same as with only one line. The problem seems to start, when the size of output exceeds certain threshold. The byte size of input doesn't matter; shorter parameters are slower, when output is bigger, which is kind of expected behavior.

Comment: If you need simple text search (not regular expressions), try using -F flag. https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14440520/3429660

Comment: Unfortunately grep -F does perform worse; the difference seems to be linearly 20% slower in all of the use cases I presented above.

Comment: I don't know whether this is doable in your case, but you could combine all of the string in a huge regular expression. Something like: `grep -E (str1|str2|str3|str4|str5) links.abc`.

Comment: The argument length doesn't seem to be the problem. See the update.